# how to remove first special character from string

Tags: javascript, html, string, jsp

I have values seperated by pipes in a database. But the issue is that I am appending | at every entry.

For Example:

|275634|374645|24354|

How can I remove the first pipe from the whole string not all the pipes.

Once inserted I don't need to check for the next time when it updates.

If I use substring(1) then it will remove the first character every time,

Please suggest a fix?

Comment: `'|275634|374645|24354|'.substring(1); // "275634|374645|24354|"` Works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `substring(index)` method where ever you want to remove the perticular special character from the String: like

```
String str2 = "|275634|374645|24354|";
 str2 = str2.substring(1);
System.out.println(str2);
```

you can see the output as `275634|374645|24354|`

Comment: thanks.. it worked. I had done some silly mistake in logic :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//input = '|275634|374645|24354|';
output = input.replace('|', '');
```

String#replace will replace the first occurance in a String. If you replace it with an empty String `''` it is removed.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZJ9u/)